# Why my DatagramChannel socket can't read my custom object?

Tags: java, nio

I'm developing a real time application in Java with communication between one server and one client with UDP socket.

It worked fine when i send and receive string but when i tried to receive a custom class Message. i got this error :java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000
at line `message = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();` in the "receiveMessage" function

I don't know why i have this error.

My Message class:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private TypeMessage typeMessage;

        private int seedMap;

        public Message(TypeMessage typeMessage) {
            this.typeMessage = typeMessage;
        }

        public TypeMessage getTypeMessage() {
            return typeMessage;
        }

        public void setTypeMessage(TypeMessage typeMessage) {
            this.typeMessage = typeMessage;
        }

        public int getSeedMap() {
            return seedMap;
        }

        public void setSeedMap(int seedMap) {
            this.seedMap = seedMap;
        }
```

My send function used by the client and the server:

```
public final static void sendMessage(Message message, DatagramChannel socketSender, InetSocketAddress addressRecever) {
    try {
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(message);
        oos.flush();
    
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        
        ByteBuffer bufferSocket = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE_BUFFER);
        bufferSocket.put(data);
        socketSender.send(bufferSocket, addressRecever);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

My receive function used by the server and the client:

```
public final static Message receiveMessage(DatagramChannel socketRecever, SocketAddress socketSender) {
    Message message = null;
    try {
        ByteBuffer bufferSocket = ByteBuffer.allocate(SIZE_BUFFER);
        bufferSocket.clear();
        
        socketSender = socketRecever.receive(bufferSocket);
        
        if(socketSender != null) {
            bufferSocket.flip();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSocket.limit()];
            bufferSocket.get(bytes);
            ByteArrayInputStream bytesStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bytesStream);
            message = (Message) objectInputStream.readObject();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return message;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: you really need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `DatagramChannel.send(ByteBuffer,SocketAddress)` sends ['the remaining bytes in the given buffer'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#send(java.nio.ByteBuffer,java.net.SocketAddress)) which is not the data you `put` but a bunch of zeros. Either `flip` first, or instead of alloc+put+flip just use `ByteBuffer.wrap(data)`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 flip the buffer fixed the probelm! thanks you for your help